# Rails and model translations: Main language in original model, translations in external store?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-i18n, globalize, mobility

I'm digging around for a Rails model translation solution that fits my needs.

I have a model `Page` with fields `title` and `content`. I already have a lot of records in its table.

Now I want to translate both title and content. I'd like to keep the `title` and `content` fields in the `pages` table (holding the main language, English) and just add translations to an external store (e.g. German).

I checked out both globalize and mobility gem. But both of them seem to force me to move everything into the external store, so I need to delete the original `title` and `content` fields in the `pages` table.

Is this true? Is there any way to do it the way I'd like to have it? Maybe with another gem?

Comment: There is no way to do this out of the box currently with Mobility, but it's something I've thought about...

Comment: I decided to use Mobility with column storage, so it doesn't matter too much for me right now. But would be a nice addition to your great gem.

Comment: Ah I see, column storage would be easy to migrate to I guess. I am thinking about providing a general purpose migrator to migrate from any backend to any other backend -- might be of interest to you if you decide later to use tables for your translations :) But still need some time to develop it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the answer to your problem, but I though of posting my comment hear.

`Globalize` will create a table for translations. You can do the same by yourself to create a table with translations for `german` and other languages. Still I believe your model will keep a `pages` table with the `title` and `content` field. `Globalize` was also not good for me so I decided to have my own implementation

This is from my `schema.rb` in my [github project](https://github.com/fabriziobertoglio1987/freeAdsWorldwide/blob/master/db/schema.rb)

```
  create_table "languages", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "iso"
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

Unluckily I don't find anymore the other models/tables, but I remember I created a table with a column for every translation required, then I would just display in my view the translation.